# Spinner not working properly in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, connected-callback

If i do this:

```
 1 async connectedCallback() {
 2    this.showSpinner = true;
 3    await this.getTableInformation();
 4    this.showSpinner = false;
 5 }
```

Spinner starts but never ends. Still a breakpoint in line 4 will show `this` as the proper context and `this.showSpinner` as false.

However If I do this:

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.getTableInformation();
}

async getTableInformation() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    const [columns, rows] = await Promise.all([ this.getColumnsConfig(), this.getRowsData()]);
    this.tableInfo = Object.assign(this.tableInfo || {}, { columns }, { rows });
    this.showSpinner = false;
}
```

It does work properly and spinner is started and ended accordingly.

html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-spinner if:true={showSpinner} variant="brand" alternative-text="Loading" size="large"> </lightning-spinner>
    <!--Something else here-->
</template>
```

Maybe is worth to mention that when saving inline edit changes, I also call this:

```
async handleInlineEditSave(event) {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    // logic here
    this.showSpinner = false;
}
```

Any idea why first version does not work?

Comment: seems fine to me, thought might be issue with using `connectedCallback` instead of `renderedCallback` but shouldn't matter. Can you also add how you use {showSpinner} in UI?

Comment: And another question is, do you set `this.showSpinner = true;` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: I added the details

Comment: have you created a property for `showSpinner` on component?

Comment: WOW... just checked... I totally forgot to do it and that was the problem. Thank you so much. If you add that as a responde I will mark it as vest answer

Comment: glad to hear, you wouldn't believe how many times it happened to me))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have created a property for `showSpinner` otherwise, UI wouldn't update